# docker image to build another image

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

Hi I need to dockerize a system. the way I have to do this like below

steps:

1. up dynamodb local instance ( just for up ).
2. run a custom script to create tables ( have to go through this to create the tables ).
3. then run the system.

I wrote a compose file also. the way I did that was, like below

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
    dynamodb:
        image: amazon/dynamodb-local
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        networks:
            - custom-network
        volumes:
            - "db-data:/home/dynamodblocal/data"

    app:
        container_name: my-app
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
                URL: ${URL}

        env_file:
            - docker.env
        depends_on:
            - dynamodb
        networks:
            - custom-network

volumes:
    db-data:

networks:
    custom-network:
```

docker file as below. ( sorry had to hide sensitive details )

```
FROM debian:buster

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG URL
RUN echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk maven awscli -y
RUN aws s3 cp ${URL} db-updater.jar

RUN echo local > input
# there are few lines of configs that wrote to input file

RUN cat input | java -jar db-updater.jar http://dynamodb:8000
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN mvn package
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java","-cp","./app/target/app-1.0.0.jar:./app/target/lib/*"]
```

my problem is looks like dynamodb do not start before the script run. so script throws a error as can't connect to server.
if I could write a custom a dynamodb with executed script that is also great. please help

Answer (score 0):

Commands in a Dockerfile can never interact with other Docker containers.  The general pattern is that an image is built once and reused, so you could delete and recreate your DynamoDB container, or run the same image on a different system, and the database setup wouldn't have happened.  Mechanically, the Dockerfile runs in an environment where it's not connected to the Compose networking system, so attempts at connecting between containers will generally fail with a "no such host" error.

A typical pattern is to use an entrypoint script to do first-time setup when the container launches.  For example, you could write a simple shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Seed the database
java -jar db-updater.jar http://dynamodb:8000 < input

# Run whatever the main container command is
exec "$@"
```

You can then include this in your Dockerfile:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .  # probably included in the `COPY . .` line
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
                                # replaces `RUN java -jar db-updater.jar`
CMD ["java", "-cp", ...]        # as in the current Dockerfile
```

If you only need this to run once when you first set up the container stack, you could also seed the data on your host.

```sh
# Outside Docker
aws s3 cp ... db-updater.jar
./make-seed-data.sh > input

# Start the DynamoDB container (only)
docker-compose up -d dynamodb

# Load the seed data
java -jar db-updater.jar -url http://localhost:8000 < input

# Now start the rest of the application
docker-compose up -d
```

This would let you remove the code to build the input file and download the updater tool from your Dockerfile.  It would also let you remove the AWS credentials from the build sequence (very important: it may be possible to find them in plain text looking at the image's `docker history`).